# Team City build agent won't build Xamarin.Forms solution

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, msbuild, teamcity

I have recently set up a new machine to act as a TeamCity build agent to add to our pool of build agents. The machine is running Windows 10 and has Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise running on it with the Xamarin build tools.

We already had 2 build agents running in the pool and they would build the application with no problems. However, when setting up this third one it refuses to build the solution.

There are multiple errors from the build log like this one:
`[Javac] obj\Release\60\android\src\md51558244f76c53b6aeda52c8a337f2c37\CarouselPageAdapter.java:5: error: package android.support.v4.view does not exist`

I've tried uninstalling visual studio several times, Changing the location of the Android SDK via Visual Studio, Setting the Environment Variable for Path to point to the SDK location, making sure the NDK is downloaded and found.

The solution builds on the machine via Visual Studio and also via MSBuild from the Developer Command Prompt but won't build using the TeamCity build agent.

I've checked the configuration of the three build agents and the users that all 3 services run under and can't find any significant differences.

Not sure what to try next, I can't put the agent in to production until it can build this solution.

Comment: You  can try to delete the bin folders and the obj folders and rebuild it ?  If it doesn’t work  ,try to  restart the VS  .

Comment: Hi @JessieZhang: The entire directory gets wiped before every build as part of the automated process. The automated process also doesn't use Visual Studio, Rather it uses MSBuild as a command line runner.